# how to set onclick signal for all qlineedit to open a widget for keyboard and send data back?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qlineedit

my project in Qt has several widget with multi qlineedit. I want when the user click on each qlineedit the second widget open to show a keyboard with single qlineedit for enter the text and number.
when the user click on ok button, the text on single qlineedit pass to the textbox's which clicked.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, i would do it as following:

1) Create QLineEdit subclass and reimplement [focusInEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusInEvent) - this will handle not only click, but other types of entering the edit also (e.g. via keyboard). In consturctor, you can connect 'openEditor' signal to your custom slot in widget responsible for that (usually the main widget).

2) Promote your edits to custom subclass.

3) From the custom focusInEvent you can, for example emit signal 'openEditor'. There you can use QObject::sender() to determine which edit emitted signal.

4) Implement slot which could do what you need (show new edit with keyboard, set the text in sender (edit emitted editor opening))

Comment: Thanks for reply, I should test it tomorrow with my PC at office.

Answer (score 0):

Either with an event filter on these line edits or by creating a subclass that implements the wanted mouse handling and using that class instead of `QLineEdit`